# how to catch shutdown signal in pyqt4 python?

Tags: python, pyqt4, shutdown

How to catch shutdown signal using QApplication.commitData in pyqt4 python? I want to properly close the program before the computer turns off.

Comment: Can't you setup a `closeEvent()` handler?

Comment: @ Blender when I shutdown the computer the closeEvent() does not trigger.

Comment: Your OS might kill the process without signaling you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try connecting to the [QApplication.aboutToQuit](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) signal, but as @Blender suggests in comments, there is no guarantee that your application will be shut down nicely. I would think that the OS would try to nicely shut down each app.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

def shuttingDown():
    print "Shutting down"

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
app.aboutToQuit.connect(shuttingDown)
w = QtGui.QWidget()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```